# PHP Symfony 2.8 Swiftmailer bundle 2.5, create message with PDF attachment from code

Tags: php, symfony, email, email-attachments, swiftmailer

I'm trying to create a SwiftMailer message using Symfony 2.8 and the SwiftMailer Bundle 2.5, where I send a PDF with a simple HTML message to an address. I can send emails, however all the example code uses methods such as addPart() and attach() which don't exist in the list of methods given by `Swift_Message` and I can't find any example that uses anything else.

I create a PDF from a rendered Twig template and then create a message to attach it to

```
$pdf = $this->get('knp_snappy.pdf')->getOutputFromHtml($response);

$message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
                ->setSubject('Hello Email')
                ->setFrom('send@example.com')
                ->setTo('recipient@example.com')
                ->setBody(
                    $this->renderView(
                    // app/Resources/views/Emails/registration.html.twig
                        'Emails/registration.html.twig',
                        array('name' => "test")
                    ),
                    'text/html'
                );
```

Attachment:
`$attachment = \Swift_Attachment::newInstance($pdf, $pdf_name, 'application/pdf');`

Both

```
$message->addPart($attachment, $contentType = "application/pdf", $charset = null);
```

and

```
$message->attach(\Swift_Attachment::fromPath('/path/to/image.jpg')->setFilename('myfilename.jpg'));
```

methods simply do not exist.

Strangely enough, the highlight message says

```
Method 'attach' not found in class \Swift_Mime_MimePart less...
Referenced method is not found in subject class.
```

But I've had no success figuring out where this comes from or how I can call the message class properly given that the `Swift_Mime_MimePart` class is several layers upward in the class hierarchy and is never called or referenced directly in the code.

Comment: I feel like there is some missing code here which will show the problem. Can you include all the code from the point where you create the `$message` variable to the point you try to run the `attach()` method?

Comment: @Augwa - It's copied pretty much straight from the 
 Swiftmailer docs themselves http://swiftmailer.org/docs/messages.html which is why I am so confused. I create the message and then try to `attach() ` right away. Should there be code in between?

Comment: I've also tried reinstalling the bundle in its entirety. I could try rolling back to an older version to see if that fixes it, but a lot of other bundles depend on this one such as FOSUserBundle so I'd reckon that would come with a set of problems on its own.

Comment: I don't think that's the problem. You said you said it's `pretty much straight` which doesn't mean exactly. I'm 99.9% certain that if you posted all the code requested that the error would reveal itself.

Comment: I changed `$this->renderView(
                    // app/Resources/views/Emails/registration.html.twig
                        'Emails/registration.html.twig',
                        array('name' => "test")
                    ),` to actually have a template for testing and moved the attach part of the code outside of the message creation as it wasn't working, as shown in the examples further down. Other than that, it's exactly like the example in terms of how much code there is. No steps missing.

Comment: If you just do `$message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()->attach(...);` does it error or not?

Comment: @Augwa - Weird, if I put all the components of the chain in the example on separate lines I don't get the method not found error where it refers to a parent class instead of the subclass. It appears calling the methods on `::newInstance` instead of the resulting object causes the interpreter to look for these methods in a parent class where `parent::_construct()` gets called? The code seems to work now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at all the individual methods called, they all end in `return $this`, which returns the instance of the object as the generic type in which the method is located in lowest the hierarchy.

Since there's no generic type loading in PHP, setBody returns `Swift_Mime_MimePart` while the other methods return `Swift_Mime_SimpleMessage`, instead of `? extends Swift_Mime_MimePart` or `? extends Swift_Mime_SimpleMessage`. Because the example sets the message in the same chain and `setBody`is the last method called, `$message` is now a `Swift_Mime_MimePart` instead of the `Swift_Message` where the `attach()` method and others are located.

The solution is therefore pretty simple; put the calls on separate lines so $message stays a `Swift_Message`

```
$message = \Swift_Message::newInstance();
$message->setSubject('Hello Email')
$message->setFrom('send@example.com')
$message->setTo('recipient@example.com')
$message->setBody(
                    $this->renderView(
                    // app/Resources/views/Emails/registration.html.twig
                        'Emails/registration.html.twig',
                        array('name' => "test")
                    ),
                    'text/html'
                );
$attachment = \Swift_Attachment::newInstance($pdf, $pdf_name, 'application/pdf');
$message->attach($attachment);
```